# Метод .toFixed(n)

Tags: javascript

```js
var i = 0;

while(i != 10) {
 i += 0.2;
 i = i.toFixed(2);
 console.log(i);
}
```

Не могу понять почему js ругается.
Кстати если добавить + к "i.toFixed(2)" то все работает, но вроде toFixed возвращает цифру а не строку.

Comment: А какая ошибка?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том что `i.toFixed(n)` возвращает значение типа `String` поэтому `+i.toFixed(2)` работает корректно